# PHP return two values from a function

Tags: php, function, return

I called a function like this in my Controller:

```
$all_calendars = Appointment::organizeAppointment($daysView['currentDay']['appointments'], $openingHours);
```

And after a long calculation, including a couple of queries, it returns a collection like this:

```
return $appointments;
```

The content of $appointments looks like this:

```
appointments:1 [▼
  "Employee1" => array: [▼
    "08:00" => ""
    "08:15" => ""
    "08:30" => ""
    "08:45" => ""
    "09:00" => Appointment {#11949 ▶}
    "09:15" => "Ja"
    "09:30" => "Ja"
    "09:45" => "Ja"
    "10:00" => Appointment {#11950 ▶}
    "10:15" => "Ja"
    "10:30" => "Ja"
    "10:45" => "Ja"
    "11:00" => ""
    "11:15" => ""
    "11:30" => ""
    "11:45" => ""
    "12:00" => Appointment {#11952 ▶}
    "12:15" => "Ja"
    "12:30" => "Ja"
    "12:45" => "Ja"
    "13:00" => Appointment {#11953 ▶}
    "13:15" => "Ja"
    "13:30" => "Ja"
    "13:45" => "Ja"
    "14:00" => Appointment {#11954 ▶}
    "14:15" => "Ja"
    "14:30" => "Ja"
    "14:45" => "Ja"
    "15:00" => Appointment {#11955 ▶}
    "15:15" => "Ja"
    "15:30" => "Ja"
    "15:45" => "Ja"
    "16:00" => Appointment {#11956 ▶}
    "16:15" => "Ja"
    "16:30" => "Ja"
    "16:45" => "Ja"
    "17:00" => ""
  ],
    "Employee2" => array: [],
    "Employee3" => array: [],
    "Employee4" => array: [],
    ...
]
```

Now I want to know how many appointments have each employee, which is just one step further adding all appointments like this:

```
$totalPerEmployee[$name] = count(array_filter($all_calendars));
```

In the case shown above the employee1 will have 7.

But I do not want to call the same process, but also I can not add this value to the end of each employees subcollection because it will break a "foreach" in the front end.

So I decided to create and store this value in a second array like this:

```
totals:1 [▼
  "Employee1" => array: [▼
    "total" => 7
  ],
    "Employee2" => array: [
    "total = 4
],
    "Employee3" => array: [],
    "Employee4" => array: [],
    ...
]
```

**My question is how do I return now TWO values from one function?**

How do I say in PHP something like this:

```
return ($appointments and $totals);  ///<--- of course this is not valid PHP
```

In just ONE call.

Answer (score 2):

Return an array containing 2 items. The original data returned and the new data

```
return (['appointments' => $appointments, 'totals' => $totals]);
```

Comment: I was sure it would be very simple! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can also return an object with stdClass.

```
$returnObj = new stdClass(); 
$returnObj->appointments = $appointments;
$returnObj->totals= $totals;

return $returnObj;
```